# How to get list of all user's relation from hierarchy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I have list of users. There is hierarchy defined by field ParentId for each user (few of users are on top of hierarchy - they have null in this field). I don't want to change structure of this table (and add for exaple hierarchyId to table).

At this moment i have this table:
Users:

```
UserId INT NOT NULL, ManagerId INT NULL, other fields
```

I need to create list of all relations user-ancestor and level differences between those users in form:

```
UserId, AncestorId, LevelDifference
```

Example:
From users table:
UserId INT NOT NULL, ManagerId INT NULL
1,NULL, (Jim)
2,1 (Josh)
3,2 (Jenny)

I should get:
UserId, AncestorId, LevelDifference
2,1,1
3,2,1
3,1,2    - (Jim is one of ancestors of Jenny)

Does anyone has some idea how to do that in fast way?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2005+ gives you [recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to work with.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about version, it is 2008 - I'm using cte to check if someone is in line of ancestors, but it is very slow to check relations between all users, there should be way to do it from other side

Comment: Would T-SQL function(s) that builds and return a memory a table be ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** - This should be what your looking for.
Using Recursive CTE as Joe Stefanelli has said:

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE [HR].[Employees](
    [empid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [mgrid] [int] NULL
);
```

**Sample Data I Am Using:**

```
empid       lastname             firstname   mgrid
----------- -------------------- ----------  -----------
1           Davis                Sara        NULL
2           Funk                 Don         1
3           Lew                  Judy        2
4           Peled                Yael        3
5           Buck                 Sven        2
6           Suurs                Paul        5
7           King                 Russell     5
8           Cameron              Maria       3
9           Dolgopyatova         Zoya        5
```

**The Query:**

```
WITH RCTE AS (

    SELECT NULL        AS PrevEmpId,
           NULL        AS PrevMgrId,
           E.empid     AS CurEmpId,
           E.mgrid     AS CurMgrid,
           0           AS [Level],
           E.lastname  AS LastName,
           E.firstname AS FirstName       
    FROM HR.Employees AS E
    WHERE E.mgrid IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PREV.CurEmpId      AS PrevEmpId,
           PREV.CurMgrid      AS PrevMgrId,
           CUR.empid          AS CurEmpId,
           CUR.mgrid          AS CurMgrId, 
           Prev.Level + 1     AS [Level],
           CUR.lastname       AS LastName,
           CUR.firstname      AS FirstName
    FROM RCTE AS PREV
    JOIN HR.Employees AS CUR ON CUR.mgrid = PREV.CurEmpId
),RAnecestors AS (

    SELECT E.empid     AS StartEmpId,
           NULL        AS PrevEmpId,
           NULL        AS PrevMgrId,
           E.empid     AS CurEmpId,
           E.mgrid     AS CurMgrid,
           1           AS [LevelDiff],
           E.lastname  AS LastName,
           E.firstname AS FirstName       
    FROM HR.Employees AS E

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PREV.StartEmpId      AS StartEmpId,
           PREV.CurEmpId        AS PrevEmpId,
           PREV.CurMgrid        AS PrevMgrId,
           CUR.empid            AS CurEmpId,
           CUR.mgrid            AS CurMgrId, 
           Prev.[LevelDiff] + 1 AS [LevelDiff],
           CUR.lastname         AS LastName,
           CUR.firstname        AS FirstName
    FROM RAnecestors AS PREV
    JOIN HR.Employees AS CUR ON CUR.empid = PREV.CurMgrid
)
SELECT RCTE.CurEmpId           AS CurrentID,
       RCTE.LastName           AS CurrentLastName,
       RAnecestors.CurEmpId    AS AncestorID,
       RAnecestors.LastName    AS AncestorLastName,
       [Level]                 AS [Level],
       [LevelDiff] - 1         AS [LevelDiff]
LEFT JOIN RAnecestors ON RAnecestors.StartEmpId = RCTE.CurEmpId
      AND RCTE.CurEmpId <> RAnecestors.CurEmpId
ORDER BY RCTE.CurEmpId, RAnecestors.LevelDiff
```

Output:

```
CurrentID   CurrentLastName      AncestorID  AncestorLastName     Level       LevelDiff
----------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
1           Davis                NULL        NULL                 0           NULL
2           Funk                 1           Davis                1           1
3           Lew                  2           Funk                 2           1
3           Lew                  1           Davis                2           2
4           Peled                3           Lew                  3           1
4           Peled                2           Funk                 3           2
4           Peled                1           Davis                3           3
5           Buck                 2           Funk                 2           1
5           Buck                 1           Davis                2           2
6           Suurs                5           Buck                 3           1
6           Suurs                2           Funk                 3           2
6           Suurs                1           Davis                3           3
7           King                 5           Buck                 3           1
7           King                 2           Funk                 3           2
7           King                 1           Davis                3           3
8           Cameron              3           Lew                  3           1
8           Cameron              2           Funk                 3           2
8           Cameron              1           Davis                3           3
9           Dolgopyatova         5           Buck                 3           1
9           Dolgopyatova         2           Funk                 3           2
9           Dolgopyatova         1           Davis                3           3
```

Comment: I see what you mean by level difference now, let me see if i can get it to work...

Comment: I have updated to show all members in tree + every single level in there ancestory as you asked for

Comment: Almost perfect. But result Davis-Davis is incorrect (Davis isn't ancestor of himself). You have to add 'WHERE RCTE.CurEmpId != RAnecestors.CurEmpId' to last select and then it'll return correct output.

Comment: @Marek - you are correct, I updated with a Left Join + Predicate instead of a where filter so that Davis (the root level) will still show up in results

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this in SQL. It's easy enough to get a list of users with ancestors using only sql, but I'm not sure how you would calculate the leveldifference without a `tree` structure. I'm not saying you can't do it with sql, I just don't know the solution off the top of my head.

I would put your users into a tree data structure. From there it would be easier to get the level difference(height of the sub-tree).

Comment: but i need this list to make faster few queries and procedures